# What does the -> arrow do in Perl?

Tags: perl

I keep seeing `->` in code and I am not exactly sure what it means. For example:

```
@top_links = @{$m->links};
```

What does this line do? Also, where can I maybe read about it?

Answer (score 40):

See [The Arrow Operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#The-Arrow-Operator) in perlop:

> "`->`" is an infix dereference operator, just as it is in C and C++. If the right side is either a `[...]`, `{...}`, or a `(...)` subscript, then the left side must be either a hard or symbolic reference to an array, a hash, or a subroutine respectively. (Or technically speaking, a location capable of holding a hard reference, if it's an array or hash reference being used for assignment.) See [perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) and [perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html).
>
> Otherwise, the right side is a method name or a simple scalar variable containing either the method name or a subroutine reference, and the left side must be either an object (a blessed reference) or a class name (that is, a package name). See [perlobj](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj.html).

Comment: The second to last line is a little misleading.  If the scalar on the right side of the arrow is a code ref, it doesn't matter at all what the left side is. With `my $say_array = sub {print "@{$_[0]}\n"};` you can then write lines like `[1, 2, 3]->$say_array;` which prints `1 2 3`

Comment: Might mention it is similar to the dot operator in many other languages such as Python, Java, Javascript, etc.

Comment: @Eric Strom: looks like a bug to me

Comment: this is simply copying/pasting docs, especially unhelpful if said docs are impenetrable.

Comment: @Community, The perlop answer is useless for someone who does not already know the answer. It assumes a knowledge of esoteric jargon and of C or C++. Can someone provide an MWE or point us to a tutorial?

Answer (score 15):

In general, `->` hints at dereference. This syntax comes from C.

In your example, it means method call: call method `links` from the object instance in `$m`. This is explained in the chapter *Objects* in [Modern Perl](http://www.onyxneon.com/books/modern_perl/). Pieces of [perlsub](http://p3rl.org/perlsub), [perlfaq7](http://p3rl.org/perlfaq7), [perlobj](http://p3rl.org/perlobj), [perltoot](http://p3rl.org/perltoot) provide the details.

For references in general, [search Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search); it is a recurring topic.

Answer (score 7):

The outer `@{}` part is a dereference - this implies `$m->links` is a *reference* to an array, so this operator deferences it to refer to the array directly, which is then copied to `@top_links`

Chapter 8 of the '[Camel Book](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596000271)' is a good place to learn about references, or the [perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html) section of the Perl documentation.

The `->` arrow operator is an object dereference, in this case fetching the `links` member of the `$m` object. Similarly, later chapters of the Camel Book cover Perl's object oriented support in detail. See the [perlobj](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj.html) section of the Perl documentation also.

Answer (score 7):

Perl arrow operator has one other use:

Class−>method invokes subroutine method in package Class

though it's completely different than your code sample. Only including it for completeness for the question in the title.