# What does -> operator do in Perl?

Tags: perl, operators

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does the -> arrow do in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4913280/what-does-the-arrow-do-in-perl)

I do not have Perl experience and I need to read some scripts.

I could not find the explanation for '->' operator.

Can you explain what does '->' operator do in this line?

```
$sftp->doSomething( $sPerson, $sCredentials )
```

Comment: It's right in Perlop: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#The-Arrow-Operator

Comment: You know it's an operator and all Perl operators are documented in the "perlop" manual page. So I'm not sure why you couldn't find the explanation. What can we do to the Perl documentation in order to make this easier?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this case, the `->` ([arrow operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#The-Arrow-Operator)) indicates an object method call - the `doSomething()` method of the object `$sftp` is being called.

Answer (score 8):

See [The Arrow Operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#The-Arrow-Operator) in perlop:

> "-> " is an infix dereference operator, just as it is in C and C++. If
>   the right side is either a [...] , {...} , or a (...) subscript, then
>   the left side must be either a hard or symbolic reference to an array,
>   a hash, or a subroutine respectively. (Or technically speaking, a
>   location capable of holding a hard reference, if it's an array or hash
>   reference being used for assignment.) See perlreftut and perlref.
>
> Otherwise, the right side is a method name or a simple scalar variable
>   containing either the method name or a subroutine reference, and the
>   left side must be either an object (a blessed reference) or a class
>   name (that is, a package name). See perlobj.

Answer (score 0):

an object `$sftp` is calling `doSomething` method by passing `$sPerson` and `$sCredentials` argument,