# What does the `->` syntax mean in Perl?

Tags: perl

```
chdir($g_var->{g_loc});
```

I found this line in some perl code I am working with and I could not figure out what the `->` means. I mean I cant find the meaning of the syntax. By the way, g_loc is the name of a folder. What am i missing here ?

P.S. i am only 4 days *into* perl.

Comment: Congratulations! You just found the feature that I loath the most about Perl: references. [perl.org has a nice tutorial](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) that I hope can help you.

Comment: For the other meaning, see [What does -> operator do in Perl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8150845/what-does-operator-do-in-perl) from yesterday and [What does the -> arrow do in Perl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4913280/what-does-the-arrow-do-in-perl).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`->` is dereferencing a reference. `$g_var` contains a reference to a `%hash` (elements of which you'd access using `$hash{key}`).

You can find more information about references in the `perlreftut` and `perlref` documentation. There's also `perllol` about lists-of-lists (nested references).

You can open the documentation using `perldoc perlreftut`, etc.

Answer (score 5):

This is what you get if you search for [perlop (perl operators)](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html) on http://perldoc.perl.org. Perldoc, the on-version of it has undergone major improvements and frankly from all reference doc I like this the best.

> "`->`" is an infix dereference operator, just as it is in C and C++. If the right side is either a `[...]` , `{...}` , or a `(...)` subscript, then the left side must be either a hard or symbolic reference to an array, a hash, or a subroutine respectively. (Or technically speaking, a location capable of holding a hard reference, if it's an array or hash reference being used for assignment.) See [perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) and [perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html).
>
> Otherwise, the right side is a method name or a simple scalar variable containing either the method name or a subroutine reference, and the left side must be either an object (a blessed reference) or a class name (that is, a package name). See [perlobj](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj.html).

Answer (score 2):

`$g_var` is a reference to a hash. The *pointer* is merely the lookup syntax, locating the "g_loc" hash entry.

It's the same as `$g_var{g_loc}` if `%g_var` were a hash rather than a hash ref.

Comment: Except $g_var can't be a hash, that would be %g_var.

Comment: Whoops, yes. Now to explain how `%g_var` and `$g_var{g_loc}` relate, given the differing sigils :(

Comment: `%g_var` references all values, `$g_var{g_loc}` references one value, `@g_var{'a', 'b'}` references two values. All from the same hash. Sigils refer to how many things you're referencing, not to the type of the variable.