# what does $a->{abcd} = '123' mean in perl?

Tags: perl

I encountered `$a->{abed} = '123'` in a Perl script in the end of a sub routine but could not make out what does this statement actually trying to do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the \`->\` syntax mean in Perl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8179722/what-does-the-syntax-mean-in-perl)

Comment: If that syntax is a problem then you have a huge amount left to learn about Perl. Stack Overflow would be a poor resource if it were full of answers to questions like *what does `$x = 99` mean?*

Comment: The answer to this question could have been discovered in 30 seconds just by reading the [official Perl documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#The-Arrow-Operator).

Comment: Another relevant part of the standard Perl documentation is the [references tutorial](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html)

Answer (score 1):

The `->` operator is a dereference. From the `{}` you can infer that what is being dereferenced is a hash ref.

So:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;


my %hash = ( 'abc' => 546 );
my $a = \%hash;
$a->{abed} = '123';

print Dumper \$a;
```

But you shouldn't use `$a` unless it's in a `sort`. Using single character var names in general is a bad thing, but `$a` and `$b` in particular have special meanings in that they're used as `sort` iterators.

Answer (score 0):

It means assign the string value `'123'` to the `'abed'` key of the `$a` hashref, which looks like this:

```
{ abed => '123' }
```

You can find more information about hashrefs in [`perldoc perlref`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html).

If this is the last line in the subroutine, then that means that the result of this expression `$a->{abed} = '123'` is returned as the return value of that subroutine, in this case that result is `'123'`.

Some notes:

1. `$a` is a poor name for a variable since it is used by the [`sort`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html) primitive