# Perl OO method call first argument value (->)

Tags: perl

In terms of Perl OO, what exactly does `->` do?

For example I make a call main:

```
$result = a::b->mymethod( );
```

In the package where I define `mymethod()`, I use the following:

```
    my( $class ) = @_;
```

In main, I clearly don’t pass any arguments to `mymethod()`, so where is the `$class` argument coming from? Has anyone got a good explanation for this or a document that explains this?

Comment: Have a look at [Beginner's Object-Oriented Tutorial](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlboot.html) and [Tom's object-oriented tutorial for perl](http://perldoc.perl.org/perltoot.html)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4913280/what-does-the-arrow-do-in-perl http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8150845/what-does-operator-do-in-perl

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [“Method Invocation” section of the perlobj documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj.html#Method-Invocation) explains. The added emphasis is mine.

> ### Method Invocation
>
> For various historical and other reasons, Perl offers two equivalent ways to write a method call. The simpler and more common way is to use the arrow notation:
>
> ```
> my $fred = Critter->find("Fred");
> $fred->display("Height", "Weight");
> ```
>
> You should already be familiar with the use of the `->` operator with references. In fact, since `$fred` above is a reference to an object, you could think of the method call as just another form of dereferencing.
>
> **Whatever is on the left side of the arrow, whether a reference or a class name, is passed to the method subroutine as its first argument.** So the above code is mostly equivalent to:
>
> ```
> my $fred = Critter::find("Critter", "Fred");
> Critter::display($fred, "Height", "Weight");
> ```
>
> How does Perl know which package the subroutine is in? By looking at the left side of the arrow, which must be either a package name or a reference to an object, *i.e.*, something that has been blessed to a package. Either way, that’s the package where Perl starts looking. If that package has no subroutine with that name, Perl starts looking for it in any base classes of that package, and so on.

Comment: Thanks for the document reference!

Answer (score 3):

The statement: `$result = a:b->mymethod( );` is wrong due to the usage of a single `:`.
The correct form is: `$result = a::b->mymethod( );`

`->` is called the *arrow operator*. It implies a method call. For method calls, the **object is implicitly passed as the first parametre** which is available via `@_` (like any other parametre), except that it is the first element.

The arrow operator differentiates a function/subroutine call and a method call.

Example:

```
Foo::Bar->method();    # Method call
Foo::Bar::function();  # Function/subroutine call
```

For a function/subroutine call, no implicit argument is passed.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

package Foo::Bar;

sub baz {
    print 'Arguments: ', scalar @_, "\n";
}

package main;

Foo::Bar::baz;
Foo::Bar->baz;
```

Relevant documents:

- [`perldoc perlobj`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj.html) - Perl Objects
- [`perldoc perlboot`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlboot.html) - Beginner's Object-Oriented Tutorial
- [`perldoc perltoot`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perltoot.html) - Tom's object-oriented tutorial for perl