# What exactly is the difference between calling a method via "->" vs passing class/object as first parameter?

Tags: perl, oop, object

From [`perldoc perlobj`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj.html#Method-Invocation) (quoted in this excellent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10784375/119280)):

> ```
> my $fred = Critter->find("Fred");
> $fred->display("Height", "Weight");
> ```
>
> ... the above code is mostly equivalent to:
>
> ```
> my $fred = Critter::find("Critter", "Fred");
> Critter::display($fred, "Height", "Weight");
> ```

What exactly is the difference, leaving aside error checking to make sure the first parameter is a blessed object or a valid class name? E.g. why is it **mostly** but not exactly the same?

Comment: "leaving aside error checking to make sure the first parameter is a blessed object or a valid class name" - that's a pretty big property to be leaving aside, isn't it?

Comment: @Mat - Correct. I left it out due to its obviousness, not due to lack of importance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Say Critter is a subclass that doesn’t define `find` or `display`—or both! The correspondence isn’t one-for-one because hardwired sub calls don’t perform method lookup, as the perlobj documentation explains.

> How does Perl know which package the subroutine is in? By looking at the left side of the arrow, which must be either a package name or a reference to an object, *i.e.*, something that has been blessed to a package. Either way, that’s the package where Perl starts looking. If that package has no subroutine with that name, Perl starts looking for it in any base classes of that package, and so on.

With a sub, you have to know exactly where it is statically, or your program will `die`. To call a method, you need only specify where to begin searching for it.

For example:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

package Critter;
sub new { bless {}, shift }
sub display { ref($_[0]) . " display" }

package SuperCritter;
@SuperCritter::ISA = qw/ Critter /;

package main;
my $super = SuperCritter->new;

# one of these things is not like the other
warn $super->display;
warn Critter::display($super);
warn SuperCritter::display($super);
```

Output:

```
SuperCritter display at ./call-demo line 14.
SuperCritter display at ./call-demo line 15.
Undefined subroutine &SuperCritter::display called at ./call-demo line 16.
```

Comment: so, calling `Critter_subclass::display` will result in a runtime error? (showing that would probably improve this already good answer by providing concrete example to a theoretical explanation).

Comment: @DVK Good suggestion! Updated.

Comment: An excellent answer, which I upvoted, and yet it manages to demonstrate that the answer to the question is mostly inheritance, without ever using the word inheritance. :)